# Multiply each row by different rotation matrix

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

This function multiplies each of the `n` rows of `pose` by a different rotation matrix. Is it possible to avoid the loop by maybe using a 3d tensor of rotation matrices?

```
def transform(ref, pose):
    n, d = pose.shape
    p = ref[:, :d].copy()
    c = np.cos(ref[:, 2])
    s = np.sin(ref[:, 2])

    for i in range(n):
        p[i,:2] += pose[i,:2].dot(np.array([[c[i], s[i]], [-s[i], c[i]]]))

    return p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
# Setup 3D rotation matrix
cs = np.empty((n,2,2))
cs[:,0,0] = c
cs[:,1,1] = c
cs[:,0,1] = s
cs[:,1,0] = -s

# Perform 3D matrix multiplications with einsum
p_out = ref[:, :d].copy()
p_out[:,:2] += np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik',pose[:,:2],cs)
```

Alternatively, replace the two assigning steps for `c` with one involving one more `einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ijj->ij',cs)[...] = c[:,None]
```

Use `optimize` flag with `True` value in `np.einsum` to leverage `BLAS`.

Alternatively, we can use `np.matmul/@ operator in Python 3.x` to replace the `einsum` part -

```
p_out[:,:2] += np.matmul(pose[:,None,:2],cs)[:,0]
```